# dplyr mutate a sequence from two columns

Tags: r

I have a seres of lists that I want to "expand" and by taking sequences. The data looks like:

```
[[10]]
  minX maxX minY maxY
1  4.9  7.9  4.9  7.9

[[11]]
  minX maxX minY maxY
1    2  3.8    2  3.8

[[12]]
  minX maxX minY maxY
1    3  6.9    3  6.9
```

I would like to create something like:

```
x <- var_lists[[1]]
seq(x[1,1], x[1, 2], length.out= 100)
```

but by name, so something like `seq(x["minX"], x["maxX"], length.out= 100)` since I also want to do it for the `minY` and `maxY` columns.

So I will end up with two new columns which are the sequences from `minX` to `maxX` and `minY` to `maxY`.

I am working in a `dplyr` pipe so I would like to do this using `mutate` or some `tidyverse` function.

Data:

```
var_lists <- list(structure(list(minX = 2, maxX = 3.8, minY = 2, maxY = 3.8), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(minX = 3, maxX = 6.9, 
    minY = 3, maxY = 6.9), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(minX = 1, maxX = 2.5, minY = 1, maxY = 2.5), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(minX = 4.9, maxX = 7.9, 
        minY = 4.9, maxY = 7.9), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(minX = 3, maxX = 6.9, minY = 3, maxY = 6.9), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(minX = 1, maxX = 2.5, 
        minY = 1, maxY = 2.5), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(minX = 4.9, maxX = 7.9, minY = 4.9, maxY = 7.9), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(minX = 2, maxX = 3.8, 
        minY = 2, maxY = 3.8), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(minX = 1, maxX = 2.5, minY = 1, maxY = 2.5), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(minX = 4.9, maxX = 7.9, 
        minY = 4.9, maxY = 7.9), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(minX = 2, maxX = 3.8, minY = 2, maxY = 3.8), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(minX = 3, maxX = 6.9, 
        minY = 3, maxY = 6.9), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map` to loop over the `list`, extract the one row column with `$` and apply `seq`

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(var_lists, ~ tibble(x = seq(.x$minX, .x$maxX, length.out = 100),
               y = seq(.x$minY, .x$maxY, length.out = 100)), .id = 'grp')
# A tibble: 1,200 x 3
#       x     y grp  
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
# 1  2     2    1    
# 2  2.02  2.02 1    
# 3  2.04  2.04 1    
# 4  2.05  2.05 1    
# 5  2.07  2.07 1    
# 6  2.09  2.09 1    
# 7  2.11  2.11 1    
# 8  2.13  2.13 1    
# 9  2.15  2.15 1    
#10  2.16  2.16 1    
# … with 1,190 more rows
```

---

If there are many columns ('X', 'Y', 'Z',...), another option is to reshape into 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and then apply on all the columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
map_dfr(var_lists,  ~ 
           .x %>%
             pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c("group", ".value"),
      names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])") %>% 
      summarise_at(-1, ~ seq(.[1], .[2], length.out = 100)), .id = 'grp') %>%
      as_tibble
# A tibble: 1,200 x 3
#       X     Y grp  
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
# 1  2     2    1    
# 2  2.02  2.02 1    
# 3  2.04  2.04 1    
# 4  2.05  2.05 1    
# 5  2.07  2.07 1    
# 6  2.09  2.09 1    
# 7  2.11  2.11 1    
# 8  2.13  2.13 1    
# 9  2.15  2.15 1    
#10  2.16  2.16 1    
# … with 1,190 more rows
```

NOTE: If we need to keep it as a `list`, replace the `map_dfr` with `map` the suffix `_dfr` suggests to return a single data.frame row bind, i.e. if it is `_dfc`, it would be column bind.  In the second  solution, if that is replaced as `map`, then `%>% as_tibble` should also be removed as it was expecting a single data.frame from the previous step

Comment: How can I keep them all as lists? I have 12 lists, how can I create 12 sequences of lists?

Comment: @user113156  Just remove the `_dfr` from `map_dfr` and it should remain as `list`

Comment: @user113156  If you are using `map` then `%>% as_tibble` needs to be removed as well because it was on the assumption that the previous step returns a single data.frame

Comment: I am using `map(., ~tibble(
    x = seq(.x$minX, .x$maxX, length.out = 100),
    y = seq(.x$minY, .x$maxY, length.out = 100)
    )
    )` it seems to work.